# Wrong cell values after merging rasters in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, merge

I have two raster files A and B which overlap in certain areas. These rasters should be merged into one while taking the exact values of raster A in the overlapping areas.

For this purpose, I intended to remove those areas from raster B which overlap with raster A in a first step, and then merge the (reduced) raster B with raster A in a second step.

To achieve this, I first generated two polygons, each with the extent of one of the rasters, via the Tile Index tool and subsequently calculated the difference of the polygons to get the extent of raster B without the overlapping areas of raster A. Then I used the tool Clip Raster by Mask Layer to clip Raster B on that extent to get rid of the overlapping parts.

When ticking the option "Keep resolution of input raster", many raster cells of the clipped raster contain (slightly) other values than the original/input raster. Also, the dimension are X: 12001 Y: 6001 instead of X: 12000 Y: 6000 of the input raster. However, the pixel size of both the input and the output files is still exactly the same. When merging the output raster with raster A, the cell values of the merged raster still have wrong values in many cells in the extent of raster B, whereas the values in the extent of raster A have the right values.

Edit: When I removed NoData values from this output raster with the tool r.null, the output file of this process has another cell size as the input file (0.0008333333333333332784 instead of 0.0008333333333333333868). I do not know if that helps in giving an advice, but I think it maybe provides more information about what could be wrong. /Edit

When leaving the option "Keep resolution of input raster" unticked, the values of the output raster are right, and also the dimensions are just right with X: 12000 Y: 6000. Also, the pixel size is the same as in the original raster. However, when merging this output raster with raster A, this time, all the values are still right except the values in the area of raster A, so it is basically the same problem as before, just the other way round.

Are there any tips on how to solve this?

Comment: Are both rasters in the same CRS? Do they fit (alignement, cellsize)? Otherwise, you should first allign both rasters so that the pixels in the overlapping parts really match 100%.

Comment: They are in the same CRS, yes. But I zoomed in on pixel size and saw that there is a very small gap and overlap, respectively, about the width of half a pixel. So I am going to try to align it perfectly and try merging it again. Thank you for the tip!